# How to get the most recently uploaded blob from google cloud storage bucket?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm using the python SDK. I know of `bucket.list_blobs()` and am able to get all the blobs, but I'm wondering - what's the best way to get the most recently uploaded one? I haven't been able to figure this out from the docs.

I can loop through them all and look at the `time_created` field, but anything more efficient?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what are going to do with the object I'd suggest looking into the Cloud Storage notifications:

1. [Object Change Notification](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification) — can notify the app when an object is updated or added to a bucket.
2. [Cloud Pub/Sub Notifications for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications) — sends a message to the Pub/Sub service. You can process the message with a handler written in my of supported languages or simply use Cloud Functions to create a lightweight server-less handler.

Just follow the links, there are some examples attached.